# Unity Вопрос про Scene и Game

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

подскажите, может кто знает, почему когда запускаешь Game в Unity вся механика игры работает, а когда пытаешься реализовать механику в окне Scene ничего не работает

P.S. Думаю, что дело в координатах, но это неточно

Comment: Scene - это сцена. Для разработки. Для передвижения объектов, рассматривания, создания игровой СЦЕНЫ. Какая еще механика там должна по вашему мнению работать? Типа функции OnMouseDown что ли?

Comment: Для отображения на сцене в Unity есть отдельные классы и методы, рекомендуемый путь гуглига: editor scripts unity